# "As we know a person longer, our point of view could change"

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is this sentence correct? Is my Usage of the word "as" acceptable here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly valid (US) English.  (Dunno how the Brits feel about it.)  It's pretty hard to replace "as", in this sense, with another concise phrasing, since it implies an effect which increases with time.

Comment: So it's 100% correct in terms of grammer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As* as a conjunction, from Google's definition:

> used to indicate that something happens during the time when something is 
>   taking place.
>
> "Frank watched him as he ambled through the crowd"
>
> synonyms:  while, just as, even as, (just) when, at the time that, at the moment that
>       "she looked up as he entered the room"

Your use of *as* is consistent with this definition.